# Chrome and Edge floating middle image below first and last, is this correct?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

It seems that in Microsoft's edge and google chrome the floating doesn't rearrange the divs properly, if you have three divs floated left and the page is scaled in a width between 444 and 436 px the third div goes to the second div's position instead of going below it. This "bug" does not occur in firefox.

I made a JSFiddle to be tested http://jsfiddle.net/e47jckrh/

HTML

```
<div id="d1">
    <p>1</p>
</div>
<div id="d2">
    <p>2</p>
</div>
<div id="d3">
    <p>3</p>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
  float: left;
}
```

Down below there is a visual representation of how it should behave

**Full page Layout**

[image: Full page]

**Correct div floating when page width is more than 444px**

[image: correct >444]

**Wrong div floating order when page width is between 444 and 436px**

[image: wrong]

**Correct div floating when page width is less than 444px**

[image: correct <444]

It may be just me thinking there is something wrong, but i assume the firefox behavior to be the correct one.

Comment: fiddle working fine on latest chrome version. please updated your chrome.

Comment: Works as expected in both Chrome and Edge

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome. I can see in your JSFiddle you're not just using Floats.. you're using a Table layout..? Is there a reason for this, your question states you're just floating the DIV's. DIV3 has no float property.

Comment: @user3847141 please check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/e47jckrh/4)

Comment: Are you sure you tested it correctly ? Cause I'm getting the same behavior  on 444 and 436px. ( same behavior as OP ). They switch places when they shouldn't.

Comment: It has something to do with margins. Problem disappears when you remove margins.

Comment: You haven't floated all the divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/e47jckrh/5/

You didn't float all your elements as you'd suggested in the question. So I added `float: left;` to the div numbered 3 and set all 3 to `display: inline-block;`.  And using `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align: center;` is a really **old** way to get something to align vertically.

These 3 lines work for most things:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with table centering. And each method doesn't work in every situation so it's good to have both in your playbook.

Comment: @Alejalapeno Of course it is good to have multiple options. But I don't believe displaying things as tables and table-cells just for the sake of vertical-centering is the best practise to follow. Layouts _used_ to entirely based upon tables. They aren't anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is caused by margin-right.

When div 2 reaches its containers right limit it overflows. In this case you control his limit by margin-right. BUT margin-right is only effective if there is succeeding element ( its calculated base on a succeeding element ). In this case div 3.

After it overflows in new line the div 3 takes its spot. But in this case margin-right has no effect since its the last element in this flow.

EDIT : I just realized you haven't floated all element , I don't know if that was your initial idea. If it was I won't delete this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. So `#d3` shouldn't be on the right side at all because it isn't floated, *but* you used `display:table`. This gives it the effect of being floated with the other two divs for some reason.

Since it uses `display: table` `#d3`'s margins are off the page but don't count as "not fitting" and don't force it to the next line.

`#d2` is floated though so its margins DO affect it. So in the small range you're experiencing this `#d1` + `#d2` won't fit because of their margins contributing to an overall larger size width but `#d1` + `#d3` will because `#d3` is not being affected by its margin on the right side giving the combo an overall smaller size width.

Simple solution is to float `#d3` as well:

```
#d3 {
    background-color: #ede4ad;
    border: 3px dotted #6e5b3c;
    clear: right;
    float: left;
}
```